# passing looped array string values to PHP range() function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, range

The following returns **Warning:** range() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Can't figure it out. Suggestions **most** welcome.

```
**<?php
echo acct_type(110);
function acct_type($acct_no)
{   $sections = array(
        'Current Asset' => '100,149',
        'Fixed Asset' => '150,159',
        'Accumulated Depreciation' => '160,169',
        'Current Liability' => '200,249',
        'Long Term Liability' => '250,299',
        'Equity' => '300,399',
        'Revenue' => '400,499',
        'Cost of Goods Sold' => '500,599',
        'Expense' => '600,699'
    );
    foreach($sections as $section => $range)
    {   if(in_array($acct_no, range($range))) return $section;
    }
}
?>**
```

Comment: Pass 2 parameters to [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range()` requires two arguments http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php
In your program you take a string that contains a text with comma inside.
You need to split the string and use the result in your `range()` function

```
foreach($sections as $section => $range)   
{
   list($min,$max)=explode(","$range);
   if(in_array($acct_no, range($min,$max)))
      return $section;   
}
```

Comment: @Grzegorz Nice! That was driving me crazy!